# S3 failing to trigger aws lambda with no error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform

Hi I want to trigger a lambda function from an s3 bucket on a any *.csv file upload.
My lambda works fine i can run it.
but seems like when i upload a csv to s3 the lambda is not triggered.
below is the code for my s3 bucket notification

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "myfirst-s3-bucket" {
  bucket = "myfirst-s3-bucket"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.myfirst-s3-bucket.id}"

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn}"
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_suffix       = ".jpg"
  }
}
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "perme_bucket" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn}"
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_s3_bucket.myfirst-s3-bucket.arn}"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I think you should be using `AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket` and not `AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch` if you want to trigger it from S3 bucket.
- Also the `filter_suffix` is for `jpg` and i think you want `.csv`
- Please find the code on github that will be helpful [github code](https://github.com/amittn/s3-trigger-lambda/blob/master/main.tf)

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "perme_bucket" {
 statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket"
 action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
 function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn}"
 principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
 source_arn    = "${aws_s3_bucket.myfirst-s3-bucket.arn}"
}
```

Comment: The `statement_id` is just a descriptive field, it has no bearing on what it does. The other fields are the important bits and are all fine so this is not the issue here even if it is confusing to read at first glance.